# Are case-bound books sized to the number of pages they contain?

Tags: paper, book-binding

Context for this question is that we're thinking of using a hard-cover book as a guestbook for an upcoming wedding. We would be putting polaroid pictures inside this guestbook. The hard-cover book is not designed for this, but is a textbook that's relevant to the couple. The worry is that putting polaroids inside the book would prevent the book from closing. I am wondering if case-bound books' binds are perfectly sized to the pages they contain or if there is some wiggle room. Also would placing a weight on top of the book for a couple of days allow things to "squeeze" into place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are, with a bit of slack.  If you stick too much in, the book will become misshapen and eventually the spine will be damaged.

I just happen to have a stack of lab books on my desk.  These are case-bound, and have had printouts stuck in (office paper, so thinner than polaroids).

[image: Lab books]

Even the bottom one on this stack is somewhat stressed.  The middle one is probably twice as thick as a new book, and the top one has got so stressed from being overstuffed and used repeatedly that the spin has come off completely.

If you want to just stick a few photos in, you can get away with it, but if you're thinking of photos on a lot of the pages, a different solution would be better.  I also have holiday note/scrapbooks at home.  These were typically made using notebooks that were themselves a souvenir, and get quite misshapen.  But they're better if you keep the photos away from the spine, and distribute them over the area of the page.  The worst case would be a full-width photo at the top of every page, with writing underneath.  Putting photos face-to-face isn't always a good idea anyway, certainly not with inkjet printed photos, so photos on facing pages should be offset in case they stick together.

If you're starting from a textbook rather than a book designed to be added to, apart from not having much space for writing, you may find the binding is tighter to start with, leaving less room for stretch

Comment: I was going to suggest that it depends on the amount of weight you use to press the book. With **enough** pressure, you could fit many times the thickness of the book between the pages with the covers still parallel. But you're probably right;  the spine would break before the carbon in the book fused into a diamond.

Comment: @fixer1234 it looks like they'd actually [explode first ](https://youtu.be/TUOCHuY_xco?t=370) (some crazy Finnish people with a massive hydraulic press tried it)

Comment: ROTFL.  I'm still cracking up at that video.

Comment: @fixer1234 their [other channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCveB47lgzZJ1WOf4XYVJNBw) is better still

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to remove some pages to compensate for the thickness of the photos. Cutting out a big chunk from some part of the book would probably be ok, but removing pages at regular intervals would be better to preserve the spine.